# update method for listview

Tags: android, sql

I make an app where whatever I save I can see it in a list view. When I want to update some of the notes I have saved it isn't updated

When I press button update, i have this  piece of code

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.bUpdate:
            boolean didItWork = true;
            try {
                String mnotes = eteli.getText().toString(); // It converts EditText to string
                DbDatabase ex = new DbDatabase(this);
                ex.open();
                ex.updateEntry(mnotes);
                ex.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                didItWork = false;
                // Set up a dialog window
                String error = e.toString(); // The dialog will refer to the exception itself
                Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                d.setTitle("Failure!");
                TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                tv.setText(error);
                d.setContentView(tv);
                d.show();

            }finally {
                if (didItWork) {
                    Toast t = Toast
                            .makeText(this, "Data has been updated successfully!",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    t.show();                   
                }
            }
            startActivity(new Intent(this, DbView.class));
            break;
}
```

In my database for updateEntry I have this

```
public long updateEntry(String mnotes) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SQLiteDatabase db1 = myHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cvUpdate = new ContentValues();   // Define updated row content
        cvUpdate.put(KEY_NOTES, mnotes);

        long i = db1.update(DATABASE_TABLE, cvUpdate, KEY_NOTES + " =? ", new String[] {mnotes});

        db1.close();
        return i;

    }
```

Any solutions?

Comment: You need the UPDATE to be in a transaction...and to commit it if sucessful

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
DbDatabase ex = new DbDatabase(YourActivity.this);
ex.open();
ex.updateEntry(mnotes);
ex.close();
```